# Particle dulpicate option not available in 2.78

Tags: dupli-groups

I want to duplicate a particle system but I don't have an option in 2.78. I clearly show a picture only two options are available in it. 1 copy active to the selected object
2 copy all to select an object

But 2.8 version has that option in the duplicate particle system.
But I want to duplicate.[image]

Comment: Why you can not use the latest version?

Comment: Because of my laptop graphic card, not an SSE

Comment: So that can't be support for my lap.